# Wanderlust -- OSX -- Emacs -- SMTP Certification Failed

Tags: macos, emacs, smtp

I am able to retrieve e-mail and navigate the various folders.  However, I cannot send any e-mail due to a certificate error (described below).  Some of the configurations out there on the internet give a path to the cert file, but OSX uses a keychain instead.  I haven't found anything on Google that describes how to set this up for OSX (Mountain Lion).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[I am `not` using gmail.]

Other users on the internet have cited a configuration similar to this:  `(setq ssl-program-name "gnutls-cli" ssl-program-arguments '("--port" service "--insecure" "--x509cafile" "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt" host))`  However, there is no such file location for certificates on OSX due to the keychain usage. I'm assuming this is the problem, but I'm not entirely sure.

I'm having the same issue with gnu e-mail, and the documentation states:

`The SMTP server may also request that you verify your identity by sending a certificate and the associated encryption key to the server. If you need to do this, you can use an ~/.authinfo entry like this:`

```
machine mail.example.org port 25 key "~/.my_smtp_tls.key" cert "~/.my_smtp_tls.cert"
```

---

This is my current configuration:

```lisp
(setq ssl-program-name "/absolute/path/to/gnutls-cli"
      ssl-program-arguments '("--insecure" "-p" service host)
      ssl-certificate-verification-policy 1)

(autoload 'wl "wl" "Wanderlust" t)
(autoload 'wl-other-frame "wl" "Wanderlust on new frame." t)
(autoload 'wl-draft "wl-draft" "Write draft with Wanderlust." t)

;; IMAP
(setq elmo-imap4-default-server "mail.mydomain.com")
(setq elmo-imap4-default-user "myusername") 
(setq elmo-imap4-default-authenticate-type 'login) 
(setq elmo-imap4-default-port '993)
(setq elmo-imap4-default-stream-type 'ssl)


(setq elmo-imap4-use-modified-utf7 t) 

;; SMTP
(setq wl-smtp-connection-type 'starttls)
(setq wl-smtp-posting-port 587)
(setq wl-smtp-authenticate-type "login")
(setq wl-smtp-posting-user "myusername")
(setq wl-smtp-posting-server "mail.mydomain.com")
(setq wl-local-domain "mydomain.com")

(setq wl-default-folder "%INBOX")
(setq wl-default-spec "%")
;; (setq wl-draft-folder "%Drafts")
(setq wl-trash-folder "%Trash")

(setq wl-folder-check-async t) 

(setq elmo-imap4-use-modified-utf7 t)

(autoload 'wl-user-agent-compose "wl-draft" nil t)
(if (boundp 'mail-user-agent)
    (setq mail-user-agent 'wl-user-agent))
(if (fboundp 'define-mail-user-agent)
    (define-mail-user-agent
      'wl-user-agent
      'wl-user-agent-compose
      'wl-draft-send
      'wl-draft-kill
      'mail-send-hook))
```

---

This is the error message when sending an e-mail:

```
*** Starting TLS handshake
- Certificate type: X.509
- Got a certificate list of 2 certificates.
- Certificate[0] info:
 - subject `OU=Domain Control Validated,CN=*.liquidweb.com', issuer `C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - G2', RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA1, activated `2013-02-22 16:03:14 UTC', expires `2018-02-22 16:03:14 UTC', SHA-1 fingerprint `f9926583e10585ca301bec7ec8d36d7e4573750d'
    Public Key Id:
        3ff7ead3d8a2be6cf1e48d072a5be80afe5183de
    Public key's random art:
        +--[ RSA 2048]----+
        |                 |
        |                 |
        |                 |
        |       .         |
        |      . S        |
        |     . o +. o    |
        |    . o E +*.B   |
        |   . . o.oooB.=  |
        |    ..o.o==+o=.  |
        +-----------------+

- Certificate[1] info:
 - subject `C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=GlobalSign Domain Validation CA - G2', issuer `C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,OU=Root CA,CN=GlobalSign Root CA', RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA1, activated `2011-04-13 10:00:00 UTC', expires `2022-04-13 10:00:00 UTC', SHA-1 fingerprint `0481c8ca31be0fa940c7e0ccd572374eadf52b73'
- Status: The certificate is NOT trusted. The certificate issuer is unknown. The name in the certificate does not match the expected. 
*** Verifying server certificate failed...
*** Fatal error: Error in the certificate.
*** Handshake has failed

byte-code: Wrong type argument: arrayp, nil
```

Comment: I think I've got it working with `(setq ssl-program-name "openssl s_client -ssl2 -connect %s:%p")`, instead of guntls.  I'll report back in another 12 to 24 hours.  I need to test it on Snow Leopard, but it appears to work on Mountain Lion.  I'm using the fcc option to place a copy in my sent folder, and it appears to leave a copy on the server if I view it so it is IMAP instead of pop in terms of reading the e-mails.

Comment: have the same problem, but unfortunately even after changing ssl-program-name to openssl doesn't help. Have you found any other solution?

Comment: I just added a sample answer with my current working setup for liquidweb shared servers.  I modified `... /lisp/net/tls.el` to remove a few gnutls-cli lines and leave just `openssl s_client -connect mail.mydomain.com:993 -no_ssl2 -ign_eof`, which avoids attempted logins using gnutls-cli configuration -- however, that is not necessary -- it just saves time logging in and eliminates the error messages in the message buffer.  Note, other gnus settings that conflict in your .emacs file would need to be commented out if they exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;; IMAP
(setq elmo-imap4-default-server "mail.mydomain.com")
(setq elmo-imap4-default-user "my-user-name") 
(setq elmo-imap4-default-authenticate-type 'login) 
(setq elmo-imap4-default-port '993)
(setq elmo-imap4-default-stream-type 'ssl)
(setq elmo-imap4-use-modified-utf7 t) 
(setq elmo-network-session-idle-timeout 30)

;; SMTP
(setq ssl-program-name "openssl s_client -ssl2 -connect %s:%p")
(setq smtpmail-auth-credentials '(("mail.mydomain.com" 587 "my-user-name" "my-password")))
(setq smtp-server "mail.mydomain.com")
```

Answer (score 1):

Well I didn't really solve the issue but was only following the workaroud using ssl with the finally correct port support by google mail. HOWEVER the issue has bitten me again while setting up another email account whose SMTP server INSISTS on STARTTLS or TLS. So the very same issue as you reported it is still open. I spend half a day searching for a solution but couldn't find one. Most interisting was that little conversation about using gnutls-cli --tofu option instead of --insecure.

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnus-english/2012-04/msg00001.html

Yet, that led me to deep into emacs and I could not find the way to change the options by which gnutls-cli is called.

The best solution to the issue would most probably be to find out where the missing keys and crts on OSX are or how to creat them and then put them in the right place. Any help, hint, comment about this?

Comment: I don't use gmail with Wanderlust, but instead use a shared server with liquidweb.  If you'd like to take a look at my configuration and my modification of the built-in tls file, be my guest:  https://github.com/lawlist/wl-config

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track using the --tofu option.  All you need to do after following the steps [here](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnus-english/2012-04/msg00001.html) is add the following in your .emacs

```
(setq starttls-extra-arguments '("--tofu"))
```

(You can also set this through emacs's customisation interface.)  This will allow you to pass any arguments to gnutls-cli you wish.